# Routing in native asp.net (not in Asp.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, config

How can asp.net routing be achieved without using mvc

As an example this is my 
localhost 
http://localhost/

and i have the **user.aspx** page

http://localhost/user.aspx

how i can get the following URLs to route to different functions on this **user.aspx** page?

http://localhost/user/example1

http://localhost/user/example1/setting

http://localhost/user/example1/setting/changeImage

http://localhost/user/example1/setting/enableView

http://localhost/user/example1/security

http://localhost/user/example/message/view

http://localhost/user/example/message/send

the important question when user request this path 
 http://localhost/user/example/message/view
and 
http://localhost/user/example/message/send
 how i can display the form of view or send

Comment: Is this an mvc app ? You tagged asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Long time back I tried the same using RouteTable and URLRewriterExtension of IIS. I wrote a blog post about it [here](http://www.cshandler.com/2011/08/easy-steps-to-url-rewriting-in-aspnet.html).

You would need a RouteTable to register routes. A custom Route handler that will return the actual page based on values coming on URL.

You can also download working sample from [MSDN Code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Easy-Steps-to-URL-2f792901).